# Maximal "Spot It!" card count

Tags: co.combinatorics

This question was triggered by the game [Spot It!](http://www.blueorangegames.com/index.php/games/spotit).

The game consists of cards, each having $k$ different symbols from an alphabet of $n>k$ symbols, with the property that any 2 cards have at least one symbol in common. This lead to a natural question: what is the maximal number $N(n,k)$ of different Spot It! cards?

It follows from pigeon-hole principle that for $n<2k$ the card deck can contain the complete set of $$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ possible choices of $k$ symbols out of the alphabet of $n$. I couldn't get the answer for $n\ge 2k$ so far.

Comment: See, e.g., http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36798/what-is-the-math-behind-the-game-spot-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240113/what-are-the-mathematical-computational-principles-behind-this-game.

Comment: For n=2k, exactly half of the sets are allowed or $\binom{n-1}{k}$.

Comment: In the actual card game, any two distinct cards have *exactly* one symbol in common.  This is Ray Chaudhuri-Wilson (as mentioned in the stackedchange solution).  Your variation, in which any two cards have *at least* one symbol in common, connects with the Erd\H{o}s-Ko-Rado theorem.  Masked Avenger's answer, which I'll rewrite as $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, is the maximum for all $n \ge 2k$.